# OS Specific package dependencies in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, npm

I have to use a npm package `email-templates` and it states that developing on OS X or Ubuntu/Linux is recommended.

As we have other people on team who are on Windows environment, so to avoid this dependency issue I started looking for something else.

Then I found `email-templates-windows` which states that to install:

**Unix/OS X**

`npm install email-templates`

**Windows**

`npm install email-templates-windows`

Is there any way I can specify this type of npm package dependencies so that it installs correct package depending on the os?

Comment: an idea. create a bash or gulp script that would execute on the postinstall command of your package.json and have that script to install the right package based on the OS

Comment: Those two modules are both published by the same publisher. The windows one has not been published for 2 years but the general one has been published in the last several days. Chances are the windows-specific one is abandonware and you should follow the windows instructions included with the general one. Try asking @niftylettuce on Twitter, the publisher of both modules. I don't think npm provides anyway to install different packages based on operating system. The package itself should take care of that. You would just have to sniff in your code anyway for the OS to know which one to load.

Comment: Okay, can you post that as an answer. I'll close this.

Answer (score -1):

```
dependencies: { "common-stuff": "*" }
overrides: {
   "os": {
      "linux": {
         "dependencies": { "email-templates-windows" }
      },
      "win32": {
         "dependencies": { "email-templates-windows" }
      }
    }
}
```

Would be nice hm?

Comment: Yes, definitely (does it really work?). But I think such things are now handled by package owners themselves by specifying "os" with their package so it would be ignored on other os.